# Keil ARM C compiler: troubles with inline functions

Tags: c, arm, keil, inline-functions

I'm porting the real-time kernel [TNeoKernel](http://goo.gl/cc5MSM) to the Cortex-M architecture, so I've installed Keil and am trying to build the kernel. However, I'm facing unexpected issues: the compiler seems not being able to handle `inline` functions. Here's simple code:

```
static inline int test(void)
{
   return 0;
}
```

Compiler's output is as follows:

```
src\appl\main.c(17): warning:  #260-D: explicit type is missing ("int" assumed)
  static inline int test(void)
src\appl\main.c(17): error:  #65: expected a ";"
  static inline int test(void)
```

If I remove the `inline` keyword, it compiles and works.

In the documentation of ARM Compiler I can't find anything about `inline` functions. So, just to make sure: is the `inline` keyword really not supported by the ARM Compiler? It is too unbelievable so I decided to ask.

I have many `static inline` functions in the kernel's platform-independent code, so, what is the best way to make it support ARM compiler? Off the top of my head, I have just two ideas:

- create architecture-dependent macro like `TN_INLINE`, and for ARM compiler it should expand to nothing;
- convert really small 1-line functions to macros.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`inline` keyword has been introduced in c99 but by [default](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armccref/armccref_babdgfjd.htm) Keil ARM C compiler compiles in c89/c90 mode.

Keil [documentation](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armcc/armcc_chr1359124227808.htm) explicitly says that `inline` is not available in c90:

> The inline keyword is not available in C90.

Keil ARM C compiler also supports c99. Use `--c99` compiler option to switch to c99 mode or try to use [`__inline`](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armccref/armccref_BABGCDCB.htm) extension keyword when in c90 mode:

Comment: Thanks. I've been read PDF documentation from infocenter.arm.com: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0471j/DUI0471J_software_development_guide.pdf , there's nothing about `--c99`.

Comment: @DmitryFrank You were not looking at the right PDF documentation: the one you linked is "ARM Compiler Software Development Guide
". The PDF compiler documentation is "armcc User Guide" http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0472j/DUI0472J_armcc_user_guide.pdf

Comment: Thanks again. I'm still quite new to the ARM ecosystem, yet learning.